# How to store data using sql loader skipping some part of text?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to run Sql Loader on following data file

```
1#text:a#hii
2#text:ab#hii
3#text:abc#hii
4#text:abcd#hello
5#text:abcde#hello
```

I want to store data in table named 'demo' as

```
c1 c2  c3
-- --- ---
1  a   hii
2  ab  hii 
3  abc hii
```

and so on.
I can't use position, because the length of `c2` can be of any length.

How to make the ctl file for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using delimiter within delimiters.

Here is the control file

load data

infile *

append into table demo
(
c1,
x filler terminated by ':',
c2,
c3
)

begindata

1#text:a#hii

2#text:ab#hii

3#text:abc#hii

4#text:abcd#hello

5#text:abcde#hello

where x is just a dummy column(not present in table) whose value is set to 'text'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position finding assuming you search for the # which seems to be the main separation of columns. Search for the position of the first #, substring out the following 5 characters ('text:'). Then find position of the next hash. Or use the position of the colon, etc. Up to you.

Check out `charindex()` in sql. The 3rd argument allows you to set a search offset.